# PHPExcel error con Codeigniter

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Estoy usando `PHPExcel` con Codeigniter de una manera bastante simple:

```
$this->load->library('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel');              
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Gastos")->setDescription("Descripcion de gastos");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'NOMBRE GASTO');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'value_1');

$i = 1;

foreach($q->result() as $row){             
     $i++;                    
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, utf8_encode($row->name));
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row->value_1);
}
```

Donde la variable `$q` es un query, estoy seguro que `$row->name` y `$row->value_1` traen correctamente los datos, para finalizar tengo este otro código:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');                                
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="GASTOS.xls"');       
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');     
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Mi problema es que al descargar el excel me muestra esta advertencia y el documento de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro encontrar el error ni poder corregir esto por más que lo intento...

Comment: El utf8_encode los utilizas para mostrar la información codificada, creo que por eso te aparecen los caracteres raros, utiliza utf8_decode.

Comment: No hay ninguna diferencia si lo pongo en `utf8_decode` o `utf8_encode` o incluso si no lo pongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la final pude solucionar mi problema cambiando esto en mi código:

```
// Código anterior
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');                                
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="GASTOS.xls"');       
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');     
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

// Código nuevo que me solucionó el problema
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$uniqid = uniqid();
$objWriter->save('./assets/files/Gastos_' . $uniqid . '.xls');
redirect(base_url('/assets/files/Gastos_' . $uniqid . '.xls'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta tu código y haciendo un par de modificaciones quedaria asi:

```html
$this->load->library('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel');              
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Gastos")->setDescription("Descripcion de gastos");

//Encabezado del excel
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'NOMBRE GASTO');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B1', 'value_1');

//Lo inicializo en dos ya que en la primera fila se va a escribir el encabezado 
$i = 2;

foreach($q->result() as $row){             
     $i++;                    
     //Decode en lugar de encode ya que lo que hace decode en decodificar el texto
     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$i, utf8_decode($row->name));
     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row->value_1);
}

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Para guardar yo ocupo un tipo diferente de sentencia pero igual me aparece lo del formato del archivo pero me lo abre de manera correcta.

```html
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="GASTOS.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Ya intenté esto y tampoco funcionó y en otro tema "no relevante" si lo inicializas en 2 va a empezar a contar desde 3... por eso lo inicializo en 1 para que empiece en 2, de igual manera muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo respondiendo

Comment: Te sigue marcando lo mismo el archivo? y si no vi que estas incrementando el valor antes de hacer la impresion

Comment: Si, sigue marcando el mismo error, @J. Castro

Comment: lo modifique siguiendo la documentación de PHPExcel prueba bro